# Update rows within the same table

Tags: sql

I am trying to update rows within a table based off of the data within the same table. Below is the query that I have written...

```
Update qf.UserCustomProperty

SET PropertyValue = '1'

SELECT      
[UserId]
FROM qf.UserCustomProperty
WHERE PropertyId = 49
and UserId IN
(SELECT
 UserId
 FROM qf.UserCustomProperty
 WHERE PropertyId = 47
 AND PropertyValue = 1)
```

I am trying to update the users that have propertyid of 49 were the same user has a propertyid of 47 and a propertyvalue of 1. The script is updating all users with a propertyid of 47 to have a propertyvalue of 1.

Comment: Actually, your current script updates ALL users to have a property value of 1, and then it does a SELECT.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The user has a propertyid of 47 and a propertyvalue of 1. That user also has a propertyid of 49 and a propertyvalue of 0. How do I update the row that has a 49 and 0 to 49 and 1?

Comment: The database is called Qflow.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've written the logic correctly but you've actually wrote it in two separate queries. I've just joined your two separate queries into one. This should work.

```
Update qf.UserCustomProperty
SET PropertyValue = '1'
WHERE PropertyId = 49
and UserId IN
(SELECT
 UserId
 FROM qf.UserCustomProperty
 WHERE PropertyId = 47
 AND PropertyValue = 1)
```

Comment: This resolved my issues. The spaces were the issue. Thanks batman!

Comment: No spaces were not the issues, your 5th, 6th, 7th lines were i.e `SELECT      
[UserId]
FROM qf.UserCustomProperty`. I've removed those to connect your two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query selects rows where the PropertyID is 47, so when its passed up to the top query, there are no records with a PropertyID of 49. You do not need the sub query, you just need a single where clause;

```
where PropertyID = 47 and PropertyID = 49 and PropertyValue = 1
```

Comment: I think your answer will not return any rows